# check if value in column A has a match in a list

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, spreadsheet

I have 2 sheets, in sheet1 list of names and IDs, and in sheet2 I have only names, I have to check each name in sheet2 if has a match from the list in sheet1 and print the id in sheet2 which associated with the same name
the list is like this:

```
Name      ID
zz         1
xx         2
cc         3
```

I tried many formulas but they don't work as I want

Comment: Have a good search on `VLOOKUP()` or `INDEX()` + `MATCH()` combinations. There will be plenty of example around on SO too.

Comment: For excel365 see `XLOOKUP()` function.

Comment: @RA Drag down the formula. It will automatically increase `E1` till your dragged cells.

Comment: @Harun24HR thank you so much, INDEX($K$1:$K$50,MATCH(E1,$J$1:$J$105,0)) and how can I refer to list in another sheet for K and J cells?

Comment: @RA See my answer and let us know your feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment, you need to mention sheet name before ranges like-

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$K$1:$K$50,MATCH(E1,Sheet2!$J$1:$J$105,0))
```